# Change navigation color on every different tab using ViewPager

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-viewpager, styles

Hello This question might have been asked but I am unable to find the answer to my question. I recently worked on a viewpage template using the following tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

This tutorail is great but now I am trying to make it so each time the user swipes to a different tab the top bar changes color. I tried adding a new style and trying to set the activity theme to a different color but no luck. If you have any ideas please help.

I have created another setupViewpage (setupViewPage2) to change between seen two and one tab when pressing the fab button that came with the template.

Java:

```
package com.example.reasults.materialpagerdesign;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import com.example.reasults.materialpagerdesign.OneFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                setupViewPager2(viewPager);

                tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        //adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "Two");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void setupViewPager2(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "Two");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

style.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppThemeTwo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">#4DAC26</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#4DAC26</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Comment: Set an `OnPageChangeListener` on the `ViewPager`, and use the `setBackgroundColor()` method to change the `Toolbar`'s color.

Comment: Hello @MikeM. Thank you for your quick response! Is there a way to change the style i am currently using? I am thinking I'll have to restart my activity and apply the new theme?

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're setting a bunch of colors. I kinda glossed over that part. Yeah, I think you do have to restart the `Activity` to change themes. I'll do a little digging to see if there's another option for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help @MikeM. I actually playe with it a little and did this and it worked perfect!:

Comment: public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                }
                if (position == 1) {
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4DAC26"));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4DAC26"));
                }

            }

Comment: Oh, good. I thought you meant you were gonna have a bunch more theme attributes, but, yeah, if it's just those few, might as well do it manually. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: eventually I will and I was thinking about that @MikeM. what would you recommend if it comes to that?

Comment: You're pretty much stuck doing it manually. You could, though, put all the color methods and whatnot in a separate method so you don't have a lot of repetitive code.

Comment: Thats true I'll look into that. Thank you again for all your help! @MikeM.

Comment: Hi @MikeM. if you add this as an answer I'll mark it as answered to give you points!